# Full working with xml Mono for Android

Tags: android, xml, xamarin.android

How is the best way for reading XML file same as RSS in standard platform with Mono for Android ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the XDocument class, it can be found in System.Xml.Linq

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("data.xml");
```

And take a look at the documentation over at MSDN.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx